# Will an object referenced within an object get garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, memory-management

```
var a = {
    b: "this";
};

a = null;
```

When removing the reference to the object literal that 'a' is referencing to in the beginning, will the reference to "this" be removed as well, or will this cause a memory leak?

Do I have to change to code to this:

```
delete a.b;
a = null;
```

?

Comment: If you dereference `a`, is there anything referencing `a.b`? I don't think there can be, because it's a string literal. It would be a different story if `a.b` were an object. Why do you want to nullify `a` anyways? Your code should be organized in a way that `a` is automatically GC'ed when it's out of scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not cause a memory leak.  A garbage collector typically works by walking the set of live references, marking the set of objects it finds and collecting anything it didn't see.  In this case neither the value initially assigned to `a` or the literal `"this"` will be found and both will be eligible for collection